# Solution to Codejam 2019's Pylons

Tags: python, performance, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve [Pylons](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051635/0000000000104e03) from the 2019's round 1A.

> Problem
>
> Our Battlestarcraft Algorithmica ship is being chased through space by
>   persistent robots called Pylons! We have just teleported to a new
>   galaxy to try to shake them off of our tail, and we want to stay here
>   for as long as possible so we can buy time to plan our next move...
>   but we do not want to get caught!
>
> This galaxy is a flat grid of R rows and C columns; the rows are
>   numbered from 1 to R from top to bottom, and the columns are numbered
>   from 1 to C from left to right. We can choose which cell to start in,
>   and we must continue to jump between cells until we have visited each
>   cell in the galaxy exactly once. That is, we can never revisit a cell,
>   including our starting cell.
>
> We do not want to make it too easy for the Pylons to guess where we
>   will go next. Each time we jump from our current cell, we must choose
>   a destination cell that does not share a row, column, or diagonal with
>   that current cell. Let (i, j) denote the cell in the i-th row and j-th
>   column; then a jump from a current cell (r, c) to a destination cell
>   (r', c') is invalid if and only if any of these is true:
>
> ```
> r = r'
> c = c'
> r - c = r' - c'
> r + c = r' + c'
> ```
>
> Can you help us find an order in which to visit each of the R × C
>   cells, such that the move between any pair of consecutive cells in the
>   sequence is valid? Or is it impossible for us to escape from the
>   Pylons? Input
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test
>   cases follow. Each consists of one line containing two integers R and
>   C: the numbers of rows and columns in this galaxy. Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where y is
>   a string of uppercase letters: either POSSIBLE or IMPOSSIBLE,
>   according to whether it is possible to fulfill the conditions in the
>   problem statement. Then, if it is possible, output R × C more lines.
>   The i-th of these lines represents the i-th cell you will visit
>   (counting starting from 1), and should contain two integers ri and ci:
>   the row and column of that cell. Note that the first of these lines
>   represents your chosen starting cell. Limits
>
> Time limit: 20 seconds per test set. Memory limit: 1GB. Test set 1
>   (Visible)
>
> T = 16. 2 ≤ R ≤ 5. 2 ≤ C ≤ 5. Test set 2 (Hidden)
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 100. 2 ≤ R ≤ 20. 2 ≤ C ≤ 20.

The analysis suggests that a brute force approach should work. However, my Python 3 solution doesn't pass the 2nd test case. Can I make it faster without complicating the algorithm?

```
from itertools import product, repeat


def main():
    T = int(input())  # the number of test cases

    for case in range(1, T+1):
        R, C = map(int, input().split())  # the numbers of rows and columns

        stack = []

        for r, c in product(range(R), range(C)):
            grid = [[False]*C for _ in repeat(None, R)]
            grid[r][c] = True
            stack.append((((r, c),), grid))

        while stack:
            moves, grid = stack.pop()
            if len(moves) == R*C:
                print('Case #{}: POSSIBLE'.format(case))
                for r, c in moves:
                    print(r+1, c+1)
                break

            for r, c in product(range(R), range(C)):
                if (not grid[r][c] and r != moves[-1][0] and c != moves[-1][1]
                        and moves[-1][0] - moves[-1][1] != r - c
                        and moves[-1][0] + moves[-1][1] != r + c):
                    g = [r.copy() for r in grid]
                    g[r][c] = True
                    stack.append((moves+((r, c),), g))
        else:
            print('Case #{}: IMPOSSIBLE'.format(case))


main()
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the analysis you've mentioned? I have a strong doubts that the brute force may work. Meanwhile, the problem looks like a [knight tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) variation with an ability to make non-knight moves. Use Warnsdorff's rule, and break the dead ends with non-knight moves.

Comment: Just follow the [link](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051635/0000000000104e03) and open the 'ANALYSIS' tab.

Comment: There is nothing about the brute force there. The do however mention the knight tour (I honestly didn't read that tab when making the above comment).

Comment: Can you add a title that explains what the task is? This way reviewers can get some context.

Comment: @vnp: Did you read it to the end? :) `This suggests that there are many possible solutions, and we might expect even more as the grid's dimensions get larger. {...} So, our intuition might suggest at this point that the best approach is some kind of brute force.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple randomized brute-force works for this problem. From the analysis:

> We can try these solutions anyway, or we can rely on our occasional
>   friend, randomness! We can pick a random starting cell, repeatedly
>   choose valid moves uniformly at random from the space of all allowed
>   moves from our current cell, and, if we run out of available moves,
>   give up and start over. For any case except for the impossible ones
>   mentioned above, this approach finds a solution very quickly.

Python code:

```
from itertools import product, repeat
from random import choice


def main():
    T = int(input())  # the number of test cases

    for case in range(1, T+1):
        R, C = map(int, input().split())  # the numbers of rows and columns

        if R < 2 or C < 2 or R + C < 7:
            print('Case #{}: IMPOSSIBLE'.format(case))
        else:
            print('Case #{}: POSSIBLE'.format(case))

            while True:
                grid = [[False]*C for _ in repeat(None, R)]
                moves = []
                last = None
                for _ in repeat(None, R*C):
                    candidates = ([(r, c) for r, c in product(range(R), range(C)) if not grid[r][c]
                                   and r != last[0] and c != last[1] and last[0] - last[1] != r - c
                                   and last[0] + last[1] != r + c]
                                  if last is not None else list(product(range(R), range(C))))
                    if not candidates:
                        break
                    cell = choice(candidates)
                    moves.append(cell)
                    grid[cell[0]][cell[1]] = True
                    last = cell
                else:
                    for r, c in moves:
                        print(r+1, c+1)
                    break


main()
```